# How to show the count of all the direct and indirect child member in wpf treeview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have one WPF tree view control which shows the Employee details in the Hierarchical way.I want to show the Employee Name and  count of their direct and indirect reportees(For example If Employee C is reporting to B and B is reporting to A , then the A's count of direct and indirect reportee will be 2)
But I am able to show the count of direct reportee(1) but not count of all  reportee(2).

I have bound the  items source from data base as list(Root) :

My xamal:

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tvMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}" BorderThickness="0">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#02747474" Background="#02000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" x:Name="AvatarPhotoBorder">
                        <Border.BitmapEffect>
                            <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="7" Softness="0.75"/>
                        </Border.BitmapEffect>
                        <Image x:Name="imgPicture"  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">            
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}">
                            <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                            <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text=" [Direct and Indirect reportee:" Foreground="LightGray" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" Foreground="Gray"  />??
                   <---- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Children.Count}"/>---->this will give only direct reportee count

                    <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="LightGray"  />
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tvMain, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

view model:

```
public class OrgElementViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int Id;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string imagePath;
    public int count;
    private ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> allchildren;

    private ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> children;

    private bool isSelected;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return GetAllChildren(); }
        set { count = GetAllChildren(); }
    }


    private int  GetAllChildren()
    {


        int dd =1;
        allchildren = new ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel>();
        //get the list of children from Model
        foreach (Node i in OrgChartManager.Instance().GetAllChildren(this.ID))
        {
            //allchildren.Add(new OrgElementViewModel(i));

            dd = dd + 1;
        }

        return dd;
    }



   public int ID
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; } 
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set { imagePath = value; }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> Children
    {
        get 
        {
            if (children == null) //not yet initialized
                return GetChildren();
            return children;
        }
        set 
        { 
            children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }

    internal OrgElementViewModel(Node i)
    {
        this.ID = i.Id;
        this.FirstName = i.FirstName;
        this.LastName = i.LastName;
        this.ImagePath = Path.GetFullPath("Images/" + this.ID.ToString() + ".png");



    }

    internal void ShowChildrenLevel(int levelsShown)

    {
        if (levelsShown == -1) //show all levels
            this.Children = GetChildren();
        else if (levelsShown == 0)  //don't show any more levels
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel>();  //set as empty
        else if (levelsShown > 0)  //if a level is requested
        {
            this.Children = GetChildren();

            foreach (OrgElementViewModel i in this.Children)
                i.ShowChildrenLevel(levelsShown - 1);  //decrement 1 for next level
        }           
    }

    private ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> GetChildren()
    {
       int dd =1;

        children = new ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel>();
        //get the list of children from Model
        foreach (Node i in OrgChartManager.Instance().GetChildren(this.ID))
        {
            children.Add(new OrgElementViewModel(i));

        }


        return children;
    }




}
```

Other class:

```
    public class OrgTreeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private static OrgTreeViewModel self;

    private List<OrgElementViewModel> root;
    private OrgElementViewModel selected;
    private ICommand selectedCommand;
    private ICommand changeDisplayLevelCommand;
    private int count;
    private int displayLevel = -1;  //display all levels by default

    //the root of the visual tree
    public List<OrgElementViewModel> Root
    {
        get 
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                root = new List<OrgElementViewModel>();
                root.Add(new OrgElementViewModel(OrgChartManager.Instance().GetRoot()));
            }
            return root;            
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(Root, "Children");; }??
    }



    public OrgElementViewModel Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            selected.IsSelected = true;
            ShowChildrenLevel();  //show only the levels chosen by the user
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    public ICommand SelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectedCommand == null)
            {
                selectedCommand = new CommandBase(i => this.SetSelected(i), null);
            }
            return selectedCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeDisplayLevelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (changeDisplayLevelCommand == null)
            {
                changeDisplayLevelCommand = new CommandBase(i => ChangeDisplayLevel(i), null);
            }
            return changeDisplayLevelCommand;
        }
    }

    private void SetSelected(object orgElement)
    {
        this.Selected = orgElement as OrgElementViewModel;
    }

    private void ChangeDisplayLevel(object i)
    {
        int level;
        if (int.TryParse(i.ToString(), out level))
        {
            this.displayLevel = level;
            ShowChildrenLevel(); //show only the levels chosen by the user
        }
    }

    private void ShowChildrenLevel()
    {
        if (this.Selected != null)
        {
            this.Selected.ShowChildrenLevel(this.displayLevel);
        }
    }

    private OrgTreeViewModel(){}

    public static OrgTreeViewModel Instance()
    {
        if (self == null)
            self = new OrgTreeViewModel();
        return self;
    }


    public int GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(IList list, string childrenPropertyName)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        foreach (object item in list)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = item.GetType().GetProperty(childrenPropertyName);
            IList childList = (IList)property.GetValue(item, null);??
            if (childList == null)
                continue;
            count += GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(childList, childrenPropertyName);
        }
        return count;
    }




}
```

My Node class:

```
    class Node
      {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; } 





}
```

My Model:

```
 public   class OrgChartManager
{
    private static OrgChartManager self;

    //orgchart stored in dictionary
    private Dictionary<int, Node> list = new Dictionary<int, Node>();

    PersonalDAL dd = new PersonalDAL();


    private OrgChartManager()
    {

        DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();
        my_datatable = new PersonalDAL().loademp();
        int ColumnCount = my_datatable.Columns.Count;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in my_datatable.Rows)
        {
            Node node = new Node
             {
                 Id = (int)dr["ID"],
                 FirstName = (string)dr["FirstName"],
                 LastName = (string)dr["LastName"],
               ParentId = (int)dr["ParentId"]

              };
            list.Add(i, node);
            i++;
        }


    }

    internal static OrgChartManager Instance()
    {
        if (self == null)
            self = new OrgChartManager();
        return self;
    }

    //get the root
    internal Node GetRoot()
    {
        return list[1];  //return the top root node
    }

    //get the directchildren of a node
    internal IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren(int parentId)
    {
               return from a in list
               where a.Value.ParentId == parentId
                    && a.Value.Id != parentId   //don't include the root, which has the same Id and ParentId
               select a.Value;


    }
    // Recursion method to get all the childeren under purcular ID
    internal IEnumerable<Node> GetAllChildren(int parentId)
    {
               var result = new List<Node>();
               var employees = from a in list
               where (a.Value.ParentId == parentId
                    && a.Value.Id != parentId)   //don't include the root, which has the same Id and ParentId 
              select a.Value;

              foreach (var employee in employees)
              {
                  result.Add(employee);
                  result.AddRange(GetAllChildren(parentId));
              }

              return result;

    }




}
```

I have modified Model class by including recursion method(GetAllChildren).But while running this method throws error  in the line   result.AddRange(GetAllChildren(parentId));

Comment: Why do you want to count from the view and not from the view model? You can create a recursive method that count all the children for each OrgElementViewModel

Answer (score -1):

If we consider that you have Children property in your tree nodes, we could use this method to count all of treeview items:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get count of every recursive objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">your list</param>
    /// <param name="childrenPropertyName">your chil property</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(IList list, string childrenPropertyName)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        foreach (object item in list)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = item.GetType().GetProperty(childrenPropertyName);
            IList childList = (IList)property.GetValue(item);
            if (childList == null)
                continue;
            count += GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(childList, childrenPropertyName);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

test:

```
int count = GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects((IList)tvMain.ItemsSource, "Children");
```

Comment: .I am getting error in line  IList childList = (IList)property.GetValue(item);"as no overload for get value takes one arguments"

Comment: where you use GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects? can i see how you use? try this too: (IList)property.GetValue(item,null);

Comment: I will call this from  internal OrgElementViewModel(Node i) inside view model as :this.Count = GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects((IList)tvMain.ItemsSource, "Children"); but here since I am in view model I cannot refer tvMain

Comment: that is example you don't need use tvMain.ItemsSource, see your xaml what is ItemsSource of tvMain binded,for example if that is "ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"" use MyCollection instade of  tvMain.ItemsSource

Comment: I have modifed  the code .. but now the count show empty  while running the code without error

Comment: check GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects is called? hovewer your binding xaml is wrong, it msut be like <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count,Source={StaticResource OrgTreeViewModel}}" Foreground="Gray"  />

Comment: change the count method to:
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCountOfEveryRecursiveObjects(Root, "Children"); ;
            }
            set
            {
            }

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count,Source={StaticResource OrgTreeViewModel}}" Foreground="Gray" /> throws the error'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.

Comment: how you set Page DataContext? is there any xaml?{StaticResource OrgTreeViewModel} is a xaml resource, example:  <Window.Resources>
  <local:OrgTreeViewModel x:Key="OrgTreeViewModel"/>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Window.DataContext>
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource OrgTreeViewModel}"/>
 </Window.DataContext>

Comment: I have given the data context in the main window  constructor:    this.DataContext = OrgTreeViewModel.Instance(); My tree view is in usercontrol whic will be called from the main window  through contentControl.

Comment: you are using ViewModel and setting datacontext manualy,you cannot access to Count property in every treeviewitem binding like this,use that binding top of treeview before itemssource or set datacontext like that i said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186797/discussion-between-faisal-thayyil-and-ali-yousefie).

Comment: I have modified Model class by including recursion method(GetAllChildren).But while running this method throws error in the line result.AddRange(GetAllChildren(parentId));

Comment: what exception?